# Where are the headers in the Azure KafkaTrigger

Tags: c#, .net, azure, apache-kafka, azure-functions

I am running an azure function as an isolated .net process, using the following packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.0.1" OutputItemType="Analyzer"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.0.0"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Kafka" Version="3.2.1"/>
```

My kafka trigger looks as follows:

```
    [Function("Function")]
    public static void Run([KafkaTrigger("broker", "topic",
        ConsumerGroup = "consumer", AuthenticationMode = BrokerAuthenticationMode.Plain)]
        string msg, FunctionContext ctx)
    {
              // no headers on msg, only:
              //   Offset
              // Partition 
              // Topic 
              // Timestamp 
              // Value

              // no headers on ctx object
    }
```

I have previously run a similar function, but in-process rather than isolated. Here, I had access to the message headers through the `KafkaEventData<string> events` object from the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Kafka` package.

As in:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Kafka;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Func
{
    public class Functions
    {
        public void Run(
            [KafkaTrigger("broker", "topic", ConsumerGroup = "consumer")] 
            KafkaEventData<string>[] events,
            ILogger log)
        {
            foreach (var kafkaEvent in events)
            {
                var headers = kafkaEvent.Headers;
                .....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using the `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Kafka` package, how does one access the headers?

Comment: Do you want to access the kafka event data headers through the extension 'Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Kafka' in code?

Comment: I updated the question to clarify my issue using the new isolated dotnet function, in contrast to the old in-process function.

Comment: Hi Rinus, when you switched from  Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Kafka to the Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Kafka did you have to change something regarding the ssl?

Answer (score 0):

I have the sample code which is used to access the headers through the ***namespace  Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Kafka*** in the azure functions.

```
public  Message<TKey, TValue> BuildFrom(IKafkaEventData  eventData)
{
    var msg = new Message<TKey, TValue>()
        {   Value = (TValue)eventData.Value;    }; 

//To check the key type
    if (eventData.Key != null)
    {
    if (!(eventData.Key is TKey keyValue))
    {
    throw new ArgumentException($"Key value is not of the expected type. Expected: {typeof(TKey).Name}. Actual: {eventData.Key.GetType().Name}");
    }
    msg.Key = keyValue;
    }

//read the headers
    if (eventData.Headers?.Count > 0)
    {
    msg.Headers = new Headers();
    foreach (var header in eventData.Headers)
    {   msg.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);  }
  }
    return msg;
```

Comment: Perhaps I am being unclear: 
In moving from Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Kafka to Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Kafka, the object received by the Trigger method is no longer of the type `KafkaEventData` but a string, along with a `FunctionContext` object. The string is json, but doesn't contain headers. Neither does the the function context. 

The docs: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/blob/main/samples/Extensions/Kafka/KafkaFunction.cs

Comment: You need to add a required headers (key-values) to the class ***KafkaEventData*** using ***IKafkaEventDataHeaders*** interface for getting the `KafkaEventData` type of object

Comment: The `KafkaEventData` is from the libraries used for in-process azure functions. Isolated functions use another library.

My `KafkaTrigger` attribute is from the worker package. Not the webjob package. Using exactly the same code, `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Kafka.Kafkatrigger` fetches headers. 
`Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Kafka.Kafkatrigger` does not.
If I try to use the webjobs trigger, I get the following error: 
**The attribute KafkaTriggerAttribute' is a WebJobs attribute and not supported in the .NET Worker (Isolated Process).**

Comment: >If I try to use the webjobs trigger, I get the following error --                                 
While using ***WebJobs*** trigger, add the following references to the *.csproj file:

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.WebJobs" Version="3.0.30" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.WebJobs.Sdk" Version="3.0" OutputItemType="Analyzer" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.WebJobs.Extensions.Http" Version="4.0.1" />
    </ItemGroup>
Please add these and check!